# Nested IF and ISNUMBER search formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I have the below formula and it works will except, when I have a refund, I want it to then show a negative value. I tried adding additional criteria but when I try to save it says I have gone over my maximum.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$100 pen",$B1)),($F1*97),
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$250 pen",$B1)),($F1*242.5),
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$500 pen",$B1)),($F1*485),
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$1000 pen",$B1)),($F1*970),0))))
```

Is there any way I can put another IF statement around this so, when the $C1 (sell price) is negative (<0), then *-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might append:

```
*IF(C1>0,1,-1)
```